# variable=@value@ in Makefiles

Tags: makefile, autoconf, gnu-make

I understand that `@` suppresses printing of a command in a Makefile...

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Echoing

... and I understand that `$@` is the target name...

http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Automatic-Variables

... but I can't find any information on what a line like this might mean:

```
variable=@value@
```

I'm not trying to fix anything here, just trying to better understand Makefiles.

Update: The "Makefile Subsitutions" section of the GNU autoconf manual explains that it's a value that is substituted by autoconf.

Comment: I don't think it means anything special; what is the context?

Comment: It's the first set of lines in the file...

prefix=@prefix@
exec_prefix=@exec_prefix@

... and so on.

Comment: What I mean is, what is this variable used for?

Comment: Some of them are clearly path variables, others are not, such as CFLAGS=@CFLAGS@ .

Comment: Are these Makefiles actually the input for autoconf or something similar?

Answer (score 4):

Typically you find this in `Makefile.in` files, which are processed by `configure` (which are in turn generated by `autoconf`) scripts.

In that case `@X@` will be replaced by the value of a shell variable `$X`, *if `configure` is told so*. If it's not, no occurrence in the input file will be touched by `configure`, hence leaving the replaceable string as it is. If you ask me these instances indicate slips in the build system.

Comment: So autoconf generates Make, which generates bash. Interesting; I'll have to look into autoconf.

Comment: @claytontstanley: Not exactly. `autoconf` usually does `configures.ac ---> configure` while the configure script itself often does `Makefile.config.in ---> Makefile.config` which in turn is included by a `Makefile` which then is read by `make` for it to determine how to build your project. `configure`, `Makefile` and `Makefile.config.in` are usually shipped with the source code.